# Unpacking tuple gives tuple size mismatch error

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, tuples, typechecking, pylance

When typechecking tuple unpacking, I get pylance errors (basic setting) on this program. The idea is that a tuple can have 2 or 3 elements of a specific type.

```
# pylance typechecking "basic"

from typing import Tuple, Union

TT = Union[Tuple[str,str,float], Tuple[str,str]]

def f(v: TT):
    if len(v) == 3:
        a,b,c = v  # pylance reportGeneralTypeIssues: Tuple size mismatch: expected 3 but received 2
    elif len(v) == 2:
        a,b = v    # pylance reportGeneralTypeIssues: Tuple size mismatch: expected 2 but received 3
```

How should I go about this to convince the checker this is correct (without #type ignore)?

Comment: Does Tuple[int, ...] work?

Comment: Looks like you can not really do anything about it. Simply the type checker there is a little bad at these situations

Answer (score 0):

I believe the solution will come with Python 3.10 by using TypeGuards. See PEP 647, which even includes an example for the number of elements in a tuple.